# Is there any car that comes from factory with a integrated dashcam?

Tags: diy, oem, dashcam

I have a car dash cam on my car and I think it does not really integrate well to the car.  It blocks some of the view and may attract thieves.

Is there any car that as an integrated dashcam from the factory?

How/where could I integrate a traditional dash cam into my car in such a way that it looks like an OEM (original equipment manufacturer) part?

Comment: I think the James Bond car has this feature.

Comment: @zipzit Edited the question to improve the readability. Still the context of the question (or a Google search) allows one to understand what a DVR is.

Comment: @zipzit I'm not being offensive. I just did not write a good question in the first attempt. If you can see how it can be improved fell free to edit it or ask for more details.

Comment: Now we're beginning to communicate. I agree with you. I know you did not mean to be offensive.  But offense in communication is in the eyes of the person receiving the message, not the person sending the message.  That's my whole point. Best way to communicate is to just do that, clearly, openly and honestly.  Its okay to use abbreviations but you should spell them out When First Used. (WFU)  does that make sense?

Comment: @zipzit Do you know any car that comes with a dashcam installed in factory?

Comment: Not I, not yet.  But i'm sure they'll be coming soon.  It wouldn't surprise me that there are some nicely designed aftermarket devices coming soon though.  I'm willing to guess too many lawyers involved in the design decision and it's just not something the automotive manufacturers want to mess with. e.g. when you record do you face front or face interior (or both).  If somebody does something flaky does it end up on the internet do they get sued, etc... you can extrapolate from there.

Comment: You can ask in Law.SE about the legality in your jurisdiction. It is legal in mine, FYI and many people that I know use these cameras, so I wondered. I just don't want that my first car with standard dash cam to be Lada :-)

Comment: I want to say the Z06 Corvette does... I'll have to look it up.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thank you! Can you write this as an answer?

Comment: Up until a few years ago, it was ILLEGAL to record a law enforcement officer in Maryland.  Someone put up a video on youtube of himself being pulled over on his bike.  The police raided his house, confiscated his computers and arrested him.  The law has since been overturned, but I'm sure this isn't true everywhere.

Comment: Also, your really not supposed to have cameras on federal property.  We do all have them on our phones, but no one says anything as long as they are not taking pictures or video.  Not sure how they would respond to mounted cameras in vehicles.  Would at least need the ability to turn the camera off.

Comment: @gabrieldiego, if you come over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) and @ my name, I can tell you what I have integrated in my car.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One notable option for an integrated dash cam is the new C7 Corvette.  As a dealer installed option, you can get a complete Performance Data Recorder (PDR) that includes a dash cam:

[image]

The PDR records GPS data, car performance information such as G-Force and steering angle and overlays everything on the through-the-windsheild POV video to give you something resembling a real-life video game.

This goes beyond a simple dash cam to record accidents or strange things crossing the street, but I think it meets the criteria of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating a dash cam into your car is doable. I used to have a GPS antenna at the top of my windscreen, wedged between the roof lining and the mirror mount. The wire ran along the edge of the roof lining, inside the A-pillar trim and through the dashboard to a power supply I'd placed in the center console behind the stereo.

You could attach the camera to the rear-view mirror (fabricate a bracket that attaches to the mirror mount). Check if you can wedge the cable between the roof lining and the window. 
If you want to run the cable behind the A-pillar trim, check if there's an airbag in there first.

This requires a bit of work and some tools (removing trim panels becomes a lot easier if you have the right tools), but an amateur like me can do it in a day.